# How do I find standard deviation for gender specific sorted data set in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

So, I am using the data.frame 'studentdata' and I have sorted the males from the females. I also created a new column called HoursSlept. Now I must find the standard deviation for males in the column HoursSlept and the same for Females.

Can someone help me??

Here is what I did but I don't know what sd it is giving me.

[image: R console code]

Comment: Could you show what `studentdata` looks like? Try running `str(studentdata)` or `head(studentdata)`. Is the gender a single column and then are you filtering on that?

Comment: Thank you for your response but someone has already answered! I'll definitely have more questions if you would be so kind lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it your way you'd have to write:

```
sd(Males$HoursSlept, na.rm = T)
sd(Females$HoursSlept, na.rm = T)
```

Because Males and Females are data.frames and you have to pass one column from the data.frames to the function. A more elegant way would be not to split the data in two data.frames. Instead you could use dplyr's filter function.

```
library(dplyr)
studentdata %>%
    filter(Gender == "male") %>%
    summarise(sd = sd(HoursSlept, na.rm = T))
```

And the same for the females. Or as @MrGumble suggested both at once with group_by:

```
studentdata %>%
   group_by(Gender) %>%
   summarise(sd = sd(HoursSlept, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: As you've introduced `dplyr`, you could smack both genders at once with `studentdata %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(sd=sd(HoursSlept, na.rm=TRUE))`.

Comment: @MrGumble Right, forgot about it. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(Hmisc)
attach(studentdata)
summarize(HoursSlept,gender,sd)
```